# Total of parent group

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables.
groups (Id,title,parentGroupID)
Accounts (AID,GroupID,Title,Balanace).

**Groups**

```
ID | Title | parentGroupID
1  | Assets| 0
2  | Bank  | 1
3  | myBank| 2
4  | cash  | 1
```

**Accounts**

```
AID | GroupID | Title        | Balanace
1   | 3       | acc1234      | 5000
2   | 3       | acc002       | 10000
3   | 4       | counter cash | 60000
```

Now I want to show assets = 5000+10000+60000 as all are member of Assets groups.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please seek guidance from the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq). Please update your answer with [what you've tried](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com).

Comment: Is there a finite number of levels of groups? (In the sample data shown there are a maximum of three levels - myBank belongs to Bank, which belongs to Assets.)

Comment: See [Managing Hierarchical Data in MySQL](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/)

Comment: there is no limit / level of groups but can be set max 5 levels.

Answer (score 0):

Play with this and see what you get:

```
SELECT
    t1.Title as Group1,
    t2.Title as Group2,
    t3.Title as Group3,
    t4.Title as Group4,
     t5.Title as Group5,
    a1.Title as SubGroup1,
    a2.Title as SubGroup2,
    a3.Title as SubGroup3,
    a4.Title as SubGroup4,
     a5.Title as SubGroup5,
    t1.parentGroupID,
    t2.parentGroupID,
    t3.parentGroupID,
    t4.parentGroupID,
    t5.parentGroupID,
    a1.Balance,
    a2.Balance,
    a3.Balance,
    a4.Balance,
     a5.Balance
           FROM GROUPS t1
      LEFT JOIN GROUPS t2 ON t2.parentGroupID = t1.ID
      LEFT JOIN GROUPS t3 ON t3.parentGroupID = t2.ID
      LEFT JOIN GROUPS t4 ON t4.parentGroupID = t3.ID
      LEFT JOIN GROUPS t5 ON t5.parentGroupID = t4.ID
      LEFT OUTER JOIN ACCOUNTS a1 ON a1.GroupID = t1.ID
      LEFT OUTER JOIN ACCOUNTS a2 ON a2.GroupID = t2.ID
      LEFT OUTER JOIN ACCOUNTS a3 ON a3.GroupID = t3.ID
      LEFT OUTER JOIN ACCOUNTS a4 ON a4.GroupID = t4.ID
      LEFT OUTER JOIN ACCOUNTS a5 on a5.GroupID = t5.ID
WHERE t1.parentGroupID = 0
```

Comment: shows result as group1, group2, group3,subgroup1...balance,balnce,blance

what I want is
groupID, GroupTtitle, balanace
1        assets           210000